# inner working of line renderer in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, away3d

I want to implement the line renderer effect in my game. I am using away3d to develop a webgame.But it seems like there is no implementation of a line renderer in away3d. So I want to know the inner working of the effect.